# nasm: fatal: unable to open input file `helloworld.asm' Permission denied

Tags: assembly, permissions, nasm

I tried to run the nasm program. But there is a permission error like bellow.
"nasm: fatal: unable to open input file `helloworld.asm' Permission denied"

How can I solve this?

Comment: Assuming you are using linux: does the `.asm` file and its parent directory have read permissions?

Comment: NASM isn't "special" in how it handles files, if `cat foo.asm > foo.out` works, so will `nasm -felf64 foo.asm`.  If it doesn't work, follow any tutorial about Unix file permissions.